# mySQL innerjoin with where condition does not work

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

i'm trying to get a result of an mysql query for the last hours but did not get it. i hope you can help me.

I have two tables. First table is called 'drives' and is quite big with more than 200000 rows and 30 columns and a structure like:

```
 plate | time from        | time to
 ab222 | 2015.05.12 08:00 | 2015.05.13 11:37
 cv481 | 2015.05.14 12:08 | 2015.05.14 14:11
```

The second is called 'fuel' and is much shorter with about 5000 rows but also 22 columns. the structure of that is like:

```
 plate | time             | amount | price
 ab222 | 2015.05.13 09:22 | 2.3    | 32.22
 cv481 | 2015.05.14 13:59 | 12.2   | 17.7
```

What I'm going to do is to show for each row in 'fuel' table the right 'drive'.  That means the time of the 'fuel' table has to be between the 'from time' and the 'to time' of the 'drives' table and the plate must be the same. The result should show the columns of both tables (so about 52 columns and 5000 rows because for each row in 'fuel' table must be one fitting drive in 'drive' table).

I'm not used to work with mysql so I googled a lot and tried a lot. The following attempt I made seems to be close to what I need:

```
INNER JOIN fuel.* ON
drives.plate = fuel.plate
WHERE fuel.time Between
drives.timefrom AND
drives.timeto
```

but it didn't work.

*****UPDATE*****

Thank you for your help so far. I played around with some querys and noticed a quite strange behaviour. But first of all you guys were right - I decided not to use 'JOIN' but query 2 tables and show the combined results. That seems to be the better solution.

But now the issue. When I'm querying in phpMyAdmin, the result is right and it shows some matches. But when I transfer the same query to php it is showing an error.

Here is how I connect to my database. That works fine:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","test"); 
mysqli_options($init, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
```

Here is the MySQL query in phpMyAdmin which works:

```
SELECT fuel.* , drives.* FROM fuel, drives WHERE fuel.plate = drives.PLATE 
AND fuel.time BETWEEN drives.time from AND drives.time to
```

Here is the same in php:

```
$con ­> query ("SELECT fuel.* , drives.* FROM fuel, drives WHERE fuel
plate = drives.PLATE AND fuel.time BETWEEN drives.time from AND 
drives.time to");
```

and it is causing the error 'Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given ERROR' in the following codeblock in the first line:

```
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($con))  {   ?>      <tr>      <td><p>
<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?></p></td>      <td><p>
<?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></p></td>      <td><p>
<?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?></p></td>      </tr>   <?php  } ?>
```

I googled a lot and find some answers like the variable $con is 'null' or the array is wrong. But if I'm using the following query to import a csv file it is working:

```
$con­>query( "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'drives.csv' INTO TABLE 
rentals FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES 
TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES");
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to get my query and the showing of the result working. sorry for annoying you, but could you please tell me, whats wrong with it? Thanks a lot.

***** WORKING SOLUTION *****

I got it working. My query was wrong. Here is the working one:

```
$blub = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT fuel.* , drives.* FROM fuel, drives 
WHERE fuel.plate = drives.PLATE AND fuel.time BETWEEN drives.time_from AND 
drives.time_to");
```

Comment: Doesn't work means? It errors or what?

Comment: I believe its `INNER JOIN fuel ON....`  There is no need of **`*`**

Comment: Please provide a complete example of what you expect a row to look like

Comment: @Rahul: it simply happens nothing. martin: the result should be  plate | time from | time to | plate | time |amount | price when the conditions I ment match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing that is most clearly wrong with the portion of SQL you posted is the inclusion of **`.*`** following the table name.

In MySQL, the addition/omission of the `INNER` keyword doesn't have any affect on the statement, i.e. `a INNER JOIN b` is synonymous with `a JOIN b`.

The predicates can appear in either the `ON` clause or the `WHERE` clause. Given that the predicates are comparisons of columns in the two tables, it's kind of odd to split them up, with one condition in the `ON` clause and the other condition in the `WHERE` clause. The database doesn't care whether those conditions are in the `ON` clause or the `WHERE` clause.  But since both of the conditions seem to be about "matching" the rows, it makes sense (to me) that these would both be in the `ON` clause.

As an example:

```
 SELECT drives.plate
      , drives.timefrom
      , drives.timeto
      , fuel.plate
      , fuel.time
      , fuel.amount
      , fuel.price
   FROM drives 
   JOIN fuel
     ON fuel.plate = drives.plate
    AND fuel.time BETWEEN drives.timefrom AND drives.timeto
```

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q:** Query causing error

```
 SELECT fuel.* , drives.* FROM fuel, drives WHERE fuel.plate = drives.PLATE 
 AND fuel.time BETWEEN drives.time from AND drives.time to
```

**A:** You have spurious spaces where there should be a column name with no space

```
              BETWEEN drives.time from AND drives.time to
                                 ^                    ^
```

If the column name has a space in it, you need to "escape" the column name by enclosing it in backticks:

```
              BETWEEN drives.`time from` AND drives.`time to` 
                             ^         ^            ^       ^
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Perhaps my previous example wasn't clear enough.

**Replace the outdated comma syntax with the JOIN keyword**

It's 2015 already. It's past time to *ditch* the old-school comma syntax for the join operation, and replace that with the newer `JOIN` keyword. (Is it really still valid to refer to the `JOIN` keyword as being "newer"?)

**Move the join predicates from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause**

The database doesn't really care; it doesn't make a difference with an inner join, a predicate is a predicate is a predicate. But we typically put the predicates that specify how rows are to be "matched" in the `ON` clause, and put the predicates that filter the resultset in the `WHERE` clause.

The reason we do this is that it makes it *easier* for the future reader to decipher and understand what the statement is doing.

Also

**Don't use .* in the SELECT list, specifically identify the expressions you need returned**

The `table_name.*` is convenient shorthand. But it is better practice to list the columns and expressions that you need to return. Very often we find that the `.*` queries return more columns than are actually needed.

While the query in your ***** WORKING SOLUTION ***** may be working, it is really less than ideal.

- replace the comma between `fuel` and `drives` with the keyword `JOIN`.
- replace the keyword `WHERE` to `ON`
- specify only the columns you need returned in the SELECT list

Comment: you have a spurious space in what should be a columname `timefrom`... here  **`BETWEEN drives.time from`**

Comment: oh yes you're right. I fixed it. but the error "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given ERROR" in the while loop is still the same

Comment: The question about that error is asked and answered, numerous times. Do a search. The `mysql_` interface is deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. Check the return from the query execution. That returns a resultset if the query is successful, and returns FALSE (a boolean) if the query isn't successful. Check for that, before you try to pass that as an argument to fetch. (If your code doesn't check the return it's effectively putting it's pinky finger to the corner of its mouth, Dr. Evil style, and saying "I just assume it will all go to plan, What?")

Comment: You're mixing mysqli and mysql interface calls. Don't do that, it doesn't work. Use mysqli only. And it looks (from the few fragments of code you posted) that you're mixing procedural style and what looks like an object oriented style function calls. I strongly recommend that you stick with one or the other. You've done a procedural style `mysqli_connect`, so do a procedural style `mysqli_query`... `$rs = mysqli_query($con,$sql); if (!$rs) { ... } else { echo "error"; }`

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
SELECT fuel.* FROM fuel 
INNER JOIN drives 
ON
drives.plate = fuel.plate
WHERE fuel.time Between
drives.timefrom AND
drives.timeto
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
INNER JOIN fuel.* ON
```

TO

```
INNER JOIN fuel  ON
drives.plate = fuel.plate
WHERE fuel.time Between
drives.timefrom AND
drives.timeto
```